# C# Printing Invoice with dot matrix printer

Tags: c#, printing

I have a dot matrix printer and an already designed invoice.

How do I print the datagridview items in the specified section of the [Invoice Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIA4V.gif)?
[image]

I searched alot for how to set boundaries in printdocument class for that purpose but I didn't found an answer. Please help...

My Application looks like this
[image]

Comment: Per your (second) screenshot... your users must have excellent vision.

Comment: What happened? Should i re-upload the second screenshot for clear vision?

Comment: Whats up with using dot matrix?

Comment: Dot Matrix?  Isn't she a C3-P0 rip-off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to do it by [this method](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196579/How-to-Print-Invoice-using-C)

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to generate a neatly formatted output is to use a reporting tool to layout your report and pass the data to it and let it worry about rendering to the printer.

There's [Crystal Reports](http://www.crystalreports.com/), [Sql Server Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx), [ActiveReports.Net](http://www.datadynamics.com/products/ActiveReports/Overview.aspx) just to name a few.